# Center tray icons popup in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, usability

I'm using [Dash to Panel](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/) to have my tray icons in the bottom-right corner of the screen, and there is something that bugs me off about the popup that the icons show when clicked.

It appears to the right of the icon, instead of being centered on it, so when I click the icon and then I try to click an option of the popup menu, it usually moves to the next icon popup, as shown in this snapshot:

[image]

Is there any way to center it?